# Google Chrome instantly closes if Terms & Conditions have not been accepted yet

Tags: android, google-chrome

I'm currently working on an app that relies on the external browser for a specific feature. For browsers that require the user to accept the Terms and Conditions on the first user access, and if this has not been done yet, the browser immediately closes itself after being launched.

So, anyone knows if there is a workaround for this? The idea would be to launch the external browser from the app, show the terms and conditions (since the user hadn't access the browser yet) and give him the possibility to accept and proceed with the normal flow.

PS: This use case was tested with a Nexus 6 and Chrome

Answer (score 0):

not sure if there's a workaround. If there is then it may be more of a hack. The t's and c's should always be accepted before first use of a browser for security and user acceptance. Google would get into trouble if they don't present this upfront, also your app may get rejected if testers pick the breach in policy up.

A possible solution though may be to try and push stored cookies into the browser from your app